# creating two different fields(in object) for one field in object(in UI)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a object `details` in which `dueAmount` and `adjustedAmount` are two fields. So my object looks like below.

```
{dueAmount:1000,adjustedAmount:1000}
```

Now if the value is changed from 1000 to 1500, then it should be as below.

```
{dueAmount:1000,adjustedAmount:1500}
```

Means `dueAmount` should hold previous value and `adjustedAmount` should hold changed value.
**Note**: In `UI`, there is only one field i.e. one `ng-model`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the issue. From the point of view of the field the user is editing, there's still only one field: `adjustedAmount`. So that's what you bind. Have you run into a problem with doing that?

Comment: `adjustedAmount` is the filed which will hold the value if and only if `dueAmount` is changed

Comment: You've shown it holding the value even when it's not changed. I'm still not seeing what the problem is.

Comment: at first both fields have same value. suppose we go for edit, then one(`dueAmount`) will hold the previous value and other(`adjustedAmount`) will hold the edited value. Sorry for not making a clear statement @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: Right. So my point is: Bind `adjustedAmount` to your input, and you're done. When the user changes it, that's the one that will change.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i don't understand this issue correctly but I'm assuming that right now when you change one value the other also changes.

In your controller you need to use angular.copy to clone the value.

this.dueAmount = angular.copy(this.adjustedAmount);

Now when adjusted amount is changed the dueAmount will not.

Comment: No, `dueAmount` should be same as it was. Only `adjustedAmount` (extra will be added from our side) for storing the changed value. Suppose when you come to the screen, `dueAmount` is 100. Then if edited to 50 from 100, now `dueAmount` is 100 only and `adjustedAmount` will be 50. :(

Comment: is this the behaviour you want? http://codepen.io/grahamfowles/pen/wgGXeN